# GMM (Método Generalizado dos Momentos) no R

Tags: r

Utilizo o GMM e gostaria de, dado um grupo de variáveis instrumentais possíveis, o R me fornecer a melhor combinação com defasagens.

Por exemplo

```
modelo GMM x ~ a b c d 
VI q y z
```

R fornecer, baseado por exemplo em um critério de informação ou outro, qual a melhor combinação de `q (-1 to x), y , z (-1 to ....)` resultante da condição mencionada.

Uso o EViews para isso, e os parâmetros seriam semelhantes à isso

```
Equation Specification
Instrument List

Estimation weighting matrix = HAC (Newey-West)
Weight updating = N-step Iterative (number of iterations - for choose)
covariance wieghting matrix = choose between White , HAC, two stages

Linear estimation with 1 weight update              
Estimation weighting matrix: HAC (Bartlett kernel, Newey-West fixed             
        bandwidth = 5.0000)             
Standard errors & covariance computed using estimation weighting matrix             
Instrument specification: xxxxx(-1 TO -6)    yyyyyyyy(-1 TO -9)
Constant added to instrument list
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta... O que é esse `q `, `y` e `z`? Você consegue colocar um exemplo de como você ajusta um modelo desse no R, para q, y e z fixados?

Comment: Marcus, boa tarde. O q seria uma variável instrumental sugerida (com defasagens de -1 à x), y e z também seriam variáveis instrumentais. Necessariamente minha pergunta é: quero obter o modelo com o melhor parâmetro que eu decidir (R2 ajustado, bic, ou outro) em função de um grupo de variáveis instrumentais, sendo que elas podem ser defasadas o quanto necessário para obter esse modelo otimizado? Ficou claro, desculpe se não fui o suficiente na primeira oportunidade.

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta que deveria ser fechada.